# Unable to create a custom reference.docx using pandoc

Tags: pandoc

On [this](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html) page:

It says:

To produce a custom reference.docx, first get a copy of the default reference.docx:

```
pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx
```

My problem is : When I run the above command it spits the output on the screen.

I do realise that I can do :

```
pandoc -o custom-reference.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx > myfile
```

My query is : Why does the first code snippet throw the output on the screen inspite of using the -o flag? What am I doing wrong ?

Also the file named myfile ONLY has the phrase "Hello world" in it.

Is that all there is in this file ?

Comment: what pandoc version are you on? try the newest pandoc version from pandoc.org/installing.html

Comment: @mb21 Thank you so much. I had pandoc 1.19.2.4. After installing the new pandoc from [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/2.7.3/pandoc-2.7.3-1-amd64.deb) and running the first command mentioned by me above I can see a proper custom-reference.docx

Answer (score 2):

No matter the version of Pandoc, you can resolve the issue by directing the output to a file instead of to the terminal.

The command to do this is:

`pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > custom-reference.docx`